# Quantum Computation and Quantum Information: Exercise 2.2

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-field-theory

The problem is,

> Suppose $V$ is a vector space with basis vectors $|0\rangle$ and
>   $|1\rangle$, and $A$ is a linear operator from $V$ to $V$ such that
>   $A|0\rangle = |1\rangle$ and $A|1\rangle = |0\rangle$. Give a matrix
>   representation for $A$, with respect to the input basis $|0\rangle,
> > |1\rangle$, and the output basis $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$. Find input
>   and output bases which give rise to a different matrix representation of
>   $A$.

By using the equation $A|v_j\rangle = \sum \limits_{i} A_{ij}|w_i\rangle$ (2.12), 
I got the matrix representation $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.
But I could't understand the latter part,

> Find input and output bases which give rise to a different matrix representation of $A$.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about another basis say $|1 \rangle - |0 \rangle$, and $|1 \rangle + |0 \rangle$, then $A$ would be different. If I understand correctly, it's basically asking for two different basis vectors of your vector space, and then a linear transformation that takes one basis vector to the other, and vice versa.